# When using an allegory from another book, do you have to stick to the most mainstream interpretation of the book?

Tags: creative-writing, allegory

When using an allegory from another book, do you have to stick to the most mainstream interpretation of the book? Metal Gear Solid: The Phantom Pain used Moby Dick as an allegory. Although I am not sure if the director chose to choose Moby Dick's mainstream interpretation. I am wondering if an author should choose to stick with the mainstream interpretation or another interpretation or his own interpretation. If the interpretation strays too away from the mainstream, how do you cue in your reader as to what your interpretation is so they don't think your work is just a jumbled mess?

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense to me. Are you asking if you need to justify your interpretation of a specific work to a reader... in a different work? Could you be more specific here?

Comment: Fiction or non-fiction? In fiction, the characters can do, say or believe anything you wan them to. in non-fiction, it depends on if it's a "hard" work (like a documentary) or a light work (like an inspirational book).